# laravel queue job running same job multiple times

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to see Laravel Queue working, but got some problems.

So I've added a testJob

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->job(new TestJob)->everyMinute();
}
```

The job class does nothing, it's just a test

```
class TestJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

As docs says, added the cron to the server

```
* * * * * cd /home/ec2-user/myproject-prod && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

For the last, added supervisor worker

```
[program:myproject-queue]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /home/ec2-user/myproject-prod/artisan queue:work --sleep=3 --tries=3
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=ec2-user
numprocs=1
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/home/ec2-user/supervisor-myproject-prod.log
```

So, as the loge below shows, at the same second you can see the same job running multiple times.

Sometimes same job runs once (correctly), a lot of times it runs twice and a few times it works 4 times.

```
[2019-11-14 08:25:02][5537] Processing: App\Jobs\TestJob
[2019-11-14 08:25:02][5537] Processed:  App\Jobs\TestJob
[2019-11-14 08:25:05][5538] Processing: App\Jobs\TestJob
[2019-11-14 08:25:05][5538] Processed:  App\Jobs\TestJob
[2019-11-14 08:26:03][5539] Processing: App\Jobs\TestJob
[2019-11-14 08:26:03][5539] Processed:  App\Jobs\TestJob
[2019-11-14 08:26:06][5540] Processing: App\Jobs\TestJob
[2019-11-14 08:26:06][5540] Processed:  App\Jobs\TestJob
[2019-11-14 08:27:03][5541] Processing: App\Jobs\TestJob
[2019-11-14 08:27:03][5541] Processed:  App\Jobs\TestJob
[2019-11-14 08:27:06][5542] Processing: App\Jobs\TestJob
[2019-11-14 08:27:06][5542] Processed:  App\Jobs\TestJob
```

Is was before running 8 processes in supervisor, so I changed to 1 and got the same problem.

Stopping the worker I can see in MySQL jobs queue it looks like correct, adding one job per minute.

So it looks like a conflict in worker.

Is that correct? Am I doing something wrong?

Is Laravel task scheduler ready for production with thousands of jobs?

Comment: Does the `available_at` field get filled in correctly when the job executes?

Comment: @Jerodev yes, each job has one minute `available_at` field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try..

```
php artisan queue:work --tries=1
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any failed jobs, so this shouldn't change the behavior.

Comment: running for 4 minutes and its correct so far. I will keep it running and check